# I can't import all the rows of my csv file in R with read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv, filesize

I have a very large dataset in a csv file. When opening it in a data visualization software (Spotfire) I can see that it has more than 7 millions rows.

However, I am working with RStudio, and when I try to open the file with read.csv2, being cautious of the quotes or other options that could affect my dataset, I end up with a 4 million file.

Here is my code when I import the file

```
my_data <- {
as.data.frame(read.csv2(file,
                        sep = ";", 
                        header = TRUE,
                        na.strings=c(""," ","NA"),
                        quote = "",
                        check.names=FALSE,
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
}
```

Moreover, when I take a look at the data in RStudio with `View(my_data)` I can see that my lines are perfectly correct

Is it related to a size limit of the files in RStudio or something like that ?

Comment: Try using `fread()` from `data.table` package for reading large data sets.

Comment: Is the last row correct?

Comment: what_alnk Indeed I didn't noticed but the last row missed some information ; SowmyaS.Manian It works perfectly thank you very much !